# My API call from Python2.7 code works but not from Python3....Getting 'Invalid id/secret key combination' hmac.new

Tags: python-3.x, hmac

I am trying to make an API call from my Python2.7 code which works, but not from python3.6....My ID/Secret Combination is not being generated correctly and I am getting a 403 response back stating ID/secret is incorrect on Python3.6. I tried every possible combination from Python3.6 but nothing works...

***Below is the code for both python2.7 and 3.6***

```
  ---------Python2.7---------
def generate_auth_string(self, method):
        authstring = "%s\n%s/%s/%s\n%s\n%s\n" % (
            self.formatted_date,
            self.service_url.rstrip('/'),  # this is merged with resource and "method" below
            self.resource.strip('/'),   # merged
            method.strip('/'),   # call scope (not http verb)
            self.content_type,
            self.method   # HTTP VERB
        )
        hash1 = hmac.new(self.secret, authstring, hashlib.sha1).digest()
        return "MPA %s:%s" % (self.key_id, base64.b64encode(hash1))

---------Python3.6---------
    def generate_auth_string(self, method):
        authstring = "%s\n%s/%s/%s\n%s\n%s\n" % (
            self.formatted_date,
            self.service_url.rstrip('/'),  # this is merged with resource and "method" below
            self.resource.strip('/'),   # merged
            method.strip('/'),   # call scope (not http verb)
            self.content_type,
            self.method   # HTTP VERB
        )
        secret = bytes(self.secret, 'utf-8')
        authstring = bytes(authstring, 'utf-8')
        return "MPA %s:%s" % (self.key_id, base64.b64encode(hmac.new(secret, authstring, hashlib.sha1).digest()).decode("utf-8"))
```